# Try-Catch not trapping exceptions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, try-catch

I wrote a simple console app in Visual Studio 10 on a Windows 7 32 bit machine using all managed code.  It works fine in debug mode, but when I deploy it to another machine and run it, I get the message,

```
[my assembly] has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.
```

... and then it generates a cryptic error report that I cannot imagine ever finding useful.  Here's the thing: the exception is occurring inside a try-catch statement that is designed to gracefully handle the error; the exception does not seem to be caught, however.

How can this be?  How can I fix it?

Comment: What are you doing in the Catch?  You could be generating another error in the Catch clause.

Comment: Can you 1)share the error 2) Check the event log and see what error is there and share that too ?

Comment: Wrap a try catch around all of your code to find where the exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the exception is thrown from a diferent place in the code, or you do not list the particular type of the exception (or one of its parent types) in the catch branches

The "cryptic" error message actually is designed to help you find out: what went wrong (the type of the exception), where did it occur (stack trace).  You should learn to read/"decypher" it

Comment: ... or for some reason you get one of the uncatchable exceptions, like StackOverflowException.

Comment: @PankajGarg - can you explain why?  With the level of detail the OP provided, I think this is a reasonable answer

Comment: Exactly, Assumption part should be in comment section.

Comment: If the OP doesn't provide enough information to answer the question you should make a comment with clarifying questions asking for the information you need to answer the question.  When/if it is provided, you can then make a meaningful answer.

Comment: I think you can still provide a meaningful (although general) answer even if you don't know the exact details of the problem

Comment: Yeah I'm an idiot.  I didn't put the constructor into my try/catch, and that's where the problem occurred.  Once I wrapped everything, it showed up.  And I agree, @Attila, your post was useful.  Comments are comments; potential solutions are answers.

Answer (score 1):

Well like Attila said, it's probably being thrown from another place. You should set the type to `Exception` as it is general and if the error is being thrown where you think it is then it definitely will end up in that catch. You can adjust the type to something more specific once the problem is understood.

Also instead of handling it gracefully, first try to print the error message to the console to see what the problem could be.

If it is not being caught it's not being thrown from inside that `try`, make sure that all the code in question is wrapped.

Comment: General `Exception` catching is frowned upon as it can catch exceptions like out-of-memory exception, which you cannot do much about

Comment: Yes you're right. My idea was to just make sure it is being caught, then to print out the error to zero in on the problem, then change the exception type accordingly to catch and handle the specific problem.